# hasMany through saving only one ID but not the other

Tags: php, cakephp

I set up a working hasMany through association with my models being

```
Drug
Record
RecordDrug
```

The 'drugs' table has two fields.

```
id | drug
```

And my 'record_drugs' table has three fields

```
id | record_id | drug_id
```

The records table is pretty unimportant except for it's 'id' field.

What I want to do; The user will have a form to submit, and one field he will be able to enter a 'drug' which the user, using autocomplete, will be able to submit an exact value that will match 'Drug.drug'. The problem i'm facing is I want to be able to find the associated ID of the drug, and then record that id into the 'record_drugs' 'drug_id' field.

Right now everything works, the correct 'record_id' is being stores with it's associated 'Record.id' value, and I want the EXACT same thing to happen except with the Drug table.

```
    $this->loadModel('RecordDrug');
    $this->loadModel('Drug');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Record->create();
        $this->request->data['Record']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->RecordDrug->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => TRUE))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
        }
    }
```

I know a possible solution would be to get the 'Drug' value submitted, and then running a query to get the id associated with it, but that seems like a cheap solution and i'd rather figure out how to get the id the right way

Comment: It depends on the autocomplete you're using, but from what I've tried here and there, you can "tell" the autocomplete to return an id to the value field, but the user selects a word... much like a simple dropdown with value-text relation. Have you look into that? Or is not what you want to do here?

Comment: I know that I could do that, but I thought that there might be a way to do it using the associatives I have set up, I thought that was a big part of the reason associatives are used. But i'll try out your suggestion